# How to access files from local and server path in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

My local path and server path is different. After production build when I upload app on server. because of the local drive path it is not working. How can I access server path ? Local path :- C:/videos/video1.mp4.
Server path :- C:/property/helpvideo/videp1.mp4.
Which path will I use in assets glob input.

Comment: How about adding that file to the `assets/` directory in your angular project?

Answer (score 0):

You can create baseUrl variable in environment.ts for development
baseUrl: 'C:/videos/'

for production create same variable baseUrl in environment.prod.ts
baseUrl: C:/property/helpvideo/

Now use this baseUrl and append file name.

Comment: Sir , I am using angular.json for this.                               In angular.json file , we have assets .                               In that I wrote like below.                                                  {"Glob":"**/*","input":"C:/videos/", output:"./assets/"}.

Comment: can you copy your video file to assets folder?

Comment: Video files are dynamic sir.. some user will put video files are on server. It keeps changing